# TCP: Why in the ACK sent by the client in the 3-way handshake needed

Tags: tcp

Why in the ACK sent by the client in the 3-way TCP handshake needed,Why can't it just start sending data in the third step?The server either ways gets to know whether the client is alive or not once it receives the data.

Comment: Because the SYN-ACK might have been lost, of course, and the server doesn't want to tie up a socket with a connection that the client doesn't know exists. There mightn't *be* any data.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing prohibiting the client from including data in the segment that contains the ACK.

However, the client shouldn't delay sending this ACK to wait for the application to send data, as it could impact RTT estimation on the server. And servers using SYN-cookies may time them out if they don't get an ACK right away.

Answer (score 1):

A typical socket-programming API will block at the "open" method until it has received the syn+ack from the host.  The communications layer should send its re-acknowledgment immediately upon receipt of that, even though since the client will be sitting in the "open" method it won't have any data to send.

If a socket API includes an "openAndSend" method which would attempt to open a socket and send some data if the attempt succeeded, then it could have data ready to transmit as soon as it receives the syn+ack from the host.  Such a thing may be worthwhile if an application will be using a lot of short-lived connections, but I've never used such a function and don't know to what extent it's supported.